# AC Motor flyback diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, induction-motor, circuit-protection

Both AC and DC motor are inductors, and flyback diodes are used to dissipate residual current when power is disconnected from the motor. Flyback diodes are always present in DC motors, do you need a diode for each of the phases of an AC motor?

Answer (score 3):

AC motors cannot use diodes to protect switches because AC polarity is always changing so sometimes metal oxide varistors are used: -

[image]

Sometimes snubbers are used: -

[image]

Sometimes snubbers are directly across the contact thus they take no power when the contact is closed but can leach a little power into the motor when the contact is open: -

[image]

Comment: I assume the Capacitor must but be rated 400V, but what's must the wattage of the capacitor?

Comment: @Golgot capacitors don't have a wattage rating.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, I was asking for the resistor... my mistake

Comment: It can be a difficult calculation and the best (simplest and most effective) is to use a simulator and get it to plot wattage peaks in several different loading scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Flyback diodes provide a path for current to flow once the DC source is removed from an inductor and its magnetic field collapses, causing huge voltage spikes across the inductor.  Since you're supplying an AC source to the AC motor you won't have this issue, and thus there's no need.

EDIT: in fact, diodes would be bad, since they would conduct for half of the AC period and short the motor phase(s).

Comment: Right, diodes are used to turn AC to DC. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So what happens if you put a diode to an outlet?